# Is it possible to store variadic arguments into a member variable?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to know if it is possible to store variadic template arguments into a member variable, for example a tuple? So I can use it in another method. I want it to work something like this, see below:

```
class TempClass
{
public:
    //How can I Store the arguments with the help of a variable?
    std::tuple<Template Args?> savedArgs;

    template<typename ...Args>
    void SaveTheseArgs(args&& ...args)
    {
        //Store the arguments into a variable for later use
        savedArgs = std::make_tuple<Args>(args);

        //Do something with the args...
    }

    void OtherMethod()
    {
        //I want to pass it back to the same method with the same arguments.
        SaveTheseArgs(savedArgs);
    }
}

//I tried a struct template like this, but this actually doesn't store them unless I am doing something wrong.
template<typename... Args>
struct StoredArguments
{
    std::tuple<Args...> StoredArgs;
};
```

I am fairly new to C++ programming. I have some experience in other languages such as C#, AS3, Java.

Comment: Your interface isn't clear.  `SaveTheseArgs` both saves them and does something with them: who uses the saved args?  Or do you just want the ability to *repeat* the (non-save-arg related) operation done by the last call to `SaveTheseArgs`?  If nobody uses them, why save them? (this is not an academic question: the plan is to type-erase down to the operation you will do with the saved args, and save that instead of the args)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I read your mind right, you save the args by not saving the args.

First, write this:

```
void DoOperation( std::tuple<int, double, std::string> const& tup ) {
  auto&& some_arg_name = std::get<0>(tup);
  auto&& second_arg_name = std::get<1>(tup);
  // etc
  // do stuff with the args
}

typedef std::function<void(TempClass*)> saved_operation;

saved_operation BuildOperation( int a, double b, std::string s ) const {
  auto tup = std::make_tuple(a,b,s);
  return [tup](TempClass* self){
    return self->DoOperation(tup);
  };
}
```

`DoOperation` takes a tuple, and does the operation using those arguments.

`BuildOperation` takes arguments, bundles them into a tuple, and generates a `saved_operation` from them.

`saved_operation` is basically a saved method call.  I don't store `this` because by avoiding that, the default copy ctor does the right thing.  Instead, you pass `this` in each time you use it.

Now using the above, we implement your stuff:

```
saved_operation saved_op;

template<typename ...Args>
void SaveTheseArgs(args&& ...args)
{
  saved_op = BuildOperation(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  saved_op(this);
}

void OtherMethod()
{
  assert(saved_op);
  saved_op(this);
}
```

A copy of the `tuple` is actually stored inside the `saved_operation` object, but that is an implementation detail.

The trick is we care not about the data, but rather what we will *do* with the data later.

I used some concrete types (the `int` `double` etc), but those can just as easily be template methods as well.

If you need the efficiency, a bit more care involving moving data around instead of copying can be useful.  But I kept it relatively simple.  If you really need a pack of any args, you might have to google the "indexes trick" to unpack the tuple of unknown content back into parameters.

In this case, `std::function` is a type erasure class that erases the details of what it is constructed from, except for the fact it can be copied, destroyed, invoked with a particular signature (and also cast-back-to-source-type, which few people use).

We exploit this to "forget" the `tuple` and instead just remember the operation we want to do on the `tuple`.

This technique can be used in more general situations: you can type erase anything with a fixed signature, or really anything that can be boiled down to a fixed signature (which is a bit broader).

Words to search for for more on this topic include "runtime concepts" and "type erasure".  Examining how `std::function` can be implemented.

Comment: I did what u suggested and it worked, thank you good sir! I will put the actually code in next time whenever I have a question. I think that will make things more clearly what I want.